OOM Issue in Streaming with foreachBatch()
I have a stateless streaming application that uses foreachBatch. This function executes between 10–400 times each hour based on custom logic.
The logic within foreachBatch includes:
collect() on very small DataFrames (a few megabytes) --> driver memory is more than 20GB so it shouldn't be an issue
Caching DataFrames and then unpersisting them
Converting a single row to a DF
Performing a cross join on a very small DataFrame
Various filtering operations
Writing the DataFrame to the target_table in append mode.
The driver memory usage gradually increases over a few days until it eventually hits a Driver Out of Memory (OOM) error.
When does Spark remove state from the driver metadata in a streaming application? Are there configurations to force more aggressive cleanup?
Could frequent calls to collect() on small DataFrames still cause driver OOM issues? What alternatives can I use?
Should I avoid caching DataFrames even if they are used multiple times within a microbatch? How can I optimize the caching strategy?
Are there specific configurations or practices to better manage driver metadata and prevent memory bloat?
The goal is to find a solution to manage and optimize driver memory usage effectively.
I've already tried tuning the GC.

Can you post your code? Interesting to see you're using collect(), cache(), unpersist(), crossjoin() all within a foreachbatch!  Haven't come across this so far.

Unfortunately, I cannot share our production data @xuxu

Well I was just looking for some reproducible code, not your production code to be precise. Hope someone can point you in the right direction.
